# Найти все div с одинаковым классом и затем вставить в них форму

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать функционал встраиваемых форм, для этого хочу чтобы на сайт нужно было подключить скрипт, и в нужные места поставить такой код:

```
<div class="EmbedForm" data-key-crm-form="d23ee2w"></div>
```

где data-key-crm-form="d23ee2w" это id по которому будет возможно встроить нужную форму с нужными настройками в нужное место сайта.

пытаюсь написать скрипт, который найдет все эти элементы и встроит в них формы, но застопарился...

Вот код:

```
    var EmbedForms = document.getElementsByClassName('EmbedForm').length;

    for( var i = 0; i < EmbedForms.length; i++ ) { 
        if (typeof EmbedForms[i].getAttribute('data-key-crm-form') == "fqeq3e2")             {
            key_crm_form = EmbedForms[i].getAttribute('data-key-crm-form');
            console.log(key_crm_form);

        }

}
```

Что я делаю не так...

Comment: `var EmbedForms = document.getElementsByClassName('EmbedForm').length;`  А что у вас `length` в конце делает ? вы же сюда элементы получить хотите, а не их количество ...

Comment: @mike согласен, лишний. забыл что length есть в цикле for

Comment: а как теперь в найденный элемент встроить код?

Comment: `EmbedForms[i].innerHTML = "<form></form>";`

Comment: все отлично... спасибо за помощь! Буду дальше ковыряться...

Answer (score 1):

Это делается очень легко при помощи jQuery

```
$('.findClass').html($('<form/>', {class: 'myClass', method: 'POST'}));
```

Если вам нужно формы с разными значениями тогда чуть по другому

```
var i = 0;
$('.findClass').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html(
        $('<form/>', {id: 'myForm' + i, class: 'myClassForm', method: 'POST'})
    );
    i++;
});
```

Comment: конечно легко с jQuery дело в том-что у меня функционал для crm с встраиваемыми формами... потому-то тут jQuery нельзя применять...